# TensorFlow (tfjs) "graphics pipeline stall"

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, graphics, gpu, tensorflow.js

I am using TensorFlow's [PoseNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) model in order to get entity recognition with a video element (stream from webcam) as the `input`.

By doing so, `tf-core` produces the following warning every frame:

`performance warning: READ-usage buffer was read back without waiting on a fence. This caused a graphics pipeline stall.`

Even though this warning appears, it seems everything is still working as intended. I am not very familiar with the language used here, it would be great if someone could explain :)

Comment: I have the same issue, the problem is that I can't draw anything over the video in the canvas :/. I tried rect, circle, text ... nothing works

Comment: @Treast That sounds like a different issue, I am able to successfully get a `Pose` object from PoseNet and draw on those coordinates. But the error appears somewhere during tfjs' process of getting a pose from an input.

Comment: I finally succeed drawing, the thing is that I was drawing the video input before calling the pose. Drawing after is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was TensorFlow v0.14.2, going back to version 0.13.3 got rid of these warnings.